# How to merge prevUser and currentUser in Firebase when using signInWithCredential?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

Forgive my lack of experience. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

- The user creates an account with a phone number,
- Then later links his account with facebook.

Now, let's assume the user changes his phone number and wants to retrieve his account by logging in on facebook.

According to this doc:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking
I should be able to do that by using the following code:

```
val prevUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val currentUser = result.user
            // Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data
            // ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // ...
        }
```

However, `prevUser` and `currentUser` always retrieve the old phone number.
What am I doing wrong?

My code is this pretty much:

```
facebook_login_button.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
facebook_login_button.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object: 
FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                mToken = loginResult.accessToken
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
            }
            override fun onCancel() {}
            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {}
        })

private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
        val prevUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        mCurrentAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                 val currentUser = result.user

             }
             .addOnFailureListener {
                 // ...
             }
}
```

I'm able to link facebook to the old phone number (which shows in Firebase). Then I use a different phone with a different number to create brand new account. Then I login in on facebook which is the same account I used on the old phone, but as I said, the currentUser's info is being replaced by the prevUser's info after I click on `facebook_login_button`.
Help please!

Comment: Hi, were u able to link Facebook with old account (created by Phone number)? Can you pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762463/how-to-prevent-multiple-account-for-same-user-in-firebase