# How to prevent multiple account for same user in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

We are developing an app using Flutter and exploring Firebase for Authentication, We have plan to provide below authentication mechanism to the end-user.

1. Login by OTP
2. Social Sign-in (Facebook/Google)

But there is a problem, in the below scenario.

1. User login by OTP (A new account get created), Lets assume U1 (user Id) and M1 (Mobile)

   U1 ----> M1
2. Now on another day same user tries to login by FaceBook (we will not get mobile from social sign in) , Only Email will be there , Now a new account will get created for that same user.

   U2 -----> E1

How do i prevent account created at step 2 (U2), as its same user ?

Tried to explore , update user profile by phone number after OTP verification, in case of social signin, but looks like one can't add phone number in case account with that number is already exist.

FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException thrown if there already exists an account with the given phone number

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential)

Can some one pls help? Anyone faced similar problem using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: By the flow that you have explained two accounts will be created always as there is no common factor that will identify that the no. and email is of same user. There is no way around for that two accounts will be created by default. If user logins with social login add a functionality to associate mobile no. with the account and then link these both accounts as per account linking documentation. When user logs in with mobile otp have option to link their social accounts with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

```
1. Login Social account (Account_2)
2. Try to link Mobile No
    If(Success)
       Account (Step1) updated with Mobile No
    Else
       Login with Mobile No (Account_1)
       Link Social account (Account_2) created in step1 with Account_1
```

Sample java script code:

```
    <script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();


var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;

var phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

provider.setCustomParameters({
  'display': 'popup'
});

var globalCred ;


firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {

  var token = result.credential.accessToken;

  globalCred = result.credential;

  console.log("GLOBAL :" + globalCred);

  var user = result.user;

  var prevUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; //Logged in via FB
  
  console.log(prevUser);

  
  if (!user.phoneNumber) {
      // Ask user for phone number.
      var phoneNumber = window.prompt('Provide your phone number');
      // You also need to provide a button element signInButtonElement
      // which the user would click to complete sign-in.
      // Get recaptcha token. Let's use invisible recaptcha and hook to the button.
      var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
          signInButtonElement, {size: 'invisible'});
      // This will wait for the button to be clicked the reCAPTCHA resolved.
      return result.user.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function(confirmationResult) {
          // Ask user to provide the SMS code.
          var code = window.prompt('Provide your SMS code');
          // Complete sign-in.
          return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
        })
    }

}).catch(function(error) {

  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  var email = error.email;

  var credential = error.credential;

  if(errorCode == 'auth/credential-already-in-use'){
      // Merge accounts      
      console.log("Trying Linking");  

      var prevUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      prevUser.delete().then(function() {
        console.log("FB user deleted");
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
        console.log("Error in FB user deletion");
      });

      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(result) {
        console.log("Sign In Success using Phone", result);
        var currentUser = result.user;

          firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(globalCred);

          });

      }).catch(function(error) {
        // If there are errors we want to undo the data merge/deletion
        console.log("Sign In Error", error);
        //repo.set(prevUser, prevUserData);
      });


  }

}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a way to identify that this is the same user, and then [link their Phone and Facebook accounts together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

The idiomatic way to identify the accounts as being from the same user is by their email address. That means you'll have to ask the Phone auth user to provide an email address to, and then [set that email address on the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address).

Comment: Yes, But adding email to Phone Auth account is async in nature (will have to send verification link to email and once user click on gthat link , thn can only that email will be added), User can any time log out and sign in with Social (Google/ Facebook).   is there any way i can add Phone number during Social Sign in and than link this account to previous account (Phone Auth) ?